# Get times looped in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'd like to get the times that I have looped in a for loop

```
for x in dictionary:
    print(timeslooped) # If the looped has looped 4 times then this should print 4
```

How would I do this?

This is a pretty simple question, but I have recently taken Python and I'm unsure about it. Thank you!

Comment: Do an Enumerate?

Comment: Call `enumerate` or increment an integer variable after (if 0-based) or before (if 1-based) to get the actual index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a counter:

```
timeslooped = 0
for x in dictionary:
    timeslooped +=1
    print(timeslooped) # If the looped has looped 4 times then this should print 4
```

or use `enumerate`:

```
for timeslooped, x in enumerate(dictionary): # enumerate returns the index and the value as a tuple
    print(timeslooped)
```

Comment: Counter feels more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` can tell you

```
for timeslooped, x in enumerate(dictionary):
    print(timeslooped+1)
```

Added `+1` because it will start at `0` rather than `1`

Comment: the second argument in `enumerate` you can specify the starting index `enumerate(dictionary,1)`

Comment: huh, all this time using `enumerate` and I never knew you could do that